# Can't run rake db:schema:load unless the database is already loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Tricky. My Rails models include lines like:

```
scope :unread, where(arel_table[:read].eq(false))
```

This line can't run, however, unless `arel_table[:read]` is defined, and it's undefined unless the column exists. (This line could be rewritten not to use Arel, but some scopes cannot.)

However, when I try to run `rake db:schema:load`, I get a `NoMethodError` resulting from the fact that `arel_table[:read]` is undefined. In short, it's a Catch-22. I can't load the database schema without running the environment, and I can't load the environment unless the database is already loaded.

Is there a better answer than "comment out all those lines then uncomment when done"? There's a number of offending lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the problem with using arel on scope. It may affect the migration. The simple solution is to just go raw SQL.

```
scope :unread, where('read = false')
```

The longer answer is that the class is somehow loaded when running the migration (it's normally is not loaded). If you can find what causes the loading of that class during the migration and work around it, then you can still use `arel_table` in the scope. But probably it's not worth it.